# XSLT: Split an xml file by number of records and split file if element text differs from the last

Tags: xml, file, xslt, split

Xml files come in with certain elements that are always there. An example is this one.

```
<xml>
   <record>
        <PieFlavor>Pie</PieFlavor>
   </record>
   <record>
        <PieFlavor>Cherry</PieFlavor>
   </record>
    <record>
        <PieFlavor>Cherry</PieFlavor>
   </record>
   <record>
        <PieFlavor>Orange</PieFlavor>
   </record>
   <record>
        <PieFlavor>Orange</PieFlavor>
   </record>
   <record>
        <PieFlavor>Orange</PieFlavor>
  </record>
</xml>
```

In this xml file the elements xml, record, and PieFlavor are always going to be there.

What I need to do is to split the xml file every certain number of records (like every 1000 records, split the file) and then also split the file every time the text in PieFlavor changes from the last one. So, if the last PieFlavor was Cherry and the current flavor is Orange, then split the file. But if the last PieFlavor was Cherry and the current PieFlavor is cherry, then continue on and split the file every certain number of records.

I got splitting the records down, then kind of got stuck when I learned I had to split the file in another way.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
    encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="recordNum" select="1000"/>
  <xsl:template match="xml">
    <xsl:for-each-group select=".//record"
      group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv $recordNum">
      <xsl:result-document  href="file:///{WATCHTEMPFOLDER}{format-number(position(),'000000000')}.xml">
        <xml>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xml>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm still kind of learning XSLT so I'm unsure of the best approach to take while trying to keep the ability of easily changing recordNum to a lower or higher number. I was thinking have a variable keep track of the element text and do checks or maybe use preceding-sibling or something, but not sure how I would fit that in.

Updated:

Here is the working version. Thanks again.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
    encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="recordNum" select="1000"/>
  <xsl:template match="xml">
    <xsl:for-each-group select=".//record" group-adjacent="PieFlavor">
      <xsl:variable name="flavor" select="concat(current-grouping-key(),position())"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv $recordNum">
        <xsl:result-document  href="file:///{WATCHTEMPFOLDER}{$flavor}{format-number(position(),'000000000')}.xml">
            <xml>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xml>
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to nest two groupings:

`<xsl:for-each-group select="//record" group-adjacent="PieFlavor">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $recordNum">`

Comment: It seems to be complaining about writing more than one document to the same URI. I put the result-document inside the nested groupings and as I debug it, it seems to get caught in the inner loop at current-group()

Comment: I would define an `<xsl:variable name="flavor" select="concat(current-grouping-key(), position())"/>` inside the outer for-each-group and then use that variable as part of the file name, to make sure you get unique file names for the result documents.

Comment: Ah thank you, that works perfectly, thank you. I figured it would have to come down to using another variable somehow.