# XSLT sorting (by attribute value) _then_ grouping (by record count)

Tags: xml, xslt

Seeking assistance to sort then group records using XSLT.

In the example shown here, the OP groups by row count, to create files with a set number of records inside them, however the records are not sorted.
[XSLT: Split an xml file by number of records and split file if element text differs from the last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538999/xslt-split-an-xml-file-by-number-of-records-and-split-file-if-element-text-diff)

Can anyone advise if it is possible to *first* sort, *then* group by a xsl:param element? I've seen example which first group, then sort. The inverse logic however does not appear to be documented anywhere.

```
<root>
  <record color="Red">
    <PieFlavor>Pie</PieFlavor>
  </record>
  <record color="Green">
    <PieFlavor>Cherry</PieFlavor>
  </record>
  <record color="Yellow">
    <PieFlavor>Cherry</PieFlavor>
  </record>
  <record color="Red">
    <PieFlavor>Orange</PieFlavor>
  </record>
  <record color="Red">
    <PieFlavor>Apple</PieFlavor>
  </record>
  <record color="Green">
    <PieFlavor>Orange</PieFlavor>
  </record>
</root>
```

When first sorting by "/root/record/@color", then grouping (into separate files) with a recordNum of 2, the resulting output should be:

```
<root>
  <record color="Green">
    <PieFlavor>Cherry</PieFlavor>
  </record>
  <record color="Green">
    <PieFlavor>Orange</PieFlavor>
  </record>
</root>

<root>
  <record color="Red">
    <PieFlavor>Pie</PieFlavor>
  </record>
  <record color="Red">
    <PieFlavor>Orange</PieFlavor>
  </record>
</root>

<root>
  <record color="Red">
    <PieFlavor>Apple</PieFlavor>
  </record>
</root>

<root>
  <record color="Yellow">
    <PieFlavor>Cherry</PieFlavor>
  </record>
</root>
```

For completeness, here's the XSLT, which does create files with only 2 records in them, but does not support sorting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="recordNum" select="2"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="root/record" group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv $recordNum">
         <xsl:result-document href="file:///{encode-for-uri('{WATCHTEMPFOLDER}')}{format-number(position(),'000000000')}.xml">
          <root>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </root>
         </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group> 
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an XSLT 2 processor? The current version (for 5 years now) is XSLT 3 and that has (from XPath 3.0) a sort function so the easiest would be doing `for-each-group select="sort(root/record, (), function($r) { $r/@color })" group-adjacent="..."`. If you are stuck with XSLT 2 then use `xsl:perform-sort`, either in a custom function you call then the same as show instead of the `sort` directly in the `select` of the `for-each-group`

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" ...>

<xsl:function name="mf:sort-records" as="element(record)*">
  <xsl:param name="records" as="element(record)*"/>
  <xsl:perform-sort select="$records">
    <xsl:sort select="@color"/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:function>

...

<xsl:for-each-group select="mf:sort-records(root/record)" group-adjacent="...">
```

or store the result in a variable and pass the variable to `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:variable name="sorted-records" as="element(record)*">
  <xsl:perform-sort select="root/record">
    <xsl:sort select="@color"/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each-group select="$sorted-records" group-adjacent="...">
```

Comment: I'll check compatibility with the utility which implements the transform, but for XSLT users this appears like a great solution.